# Neat Error: Invalid CSS "!global !default;"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, neat

I'm using bourbon and Neat with rails application.
I can't make Neat run, one of the most common error that I get is:

```
error stylesheets/sass/neat/functions/_private.scss (Line 48: Invalid CSS after "... $grid-columns ": expected "}", was "!global !default;")
```

(and if I comment this line will be just another line)

I'm using Neat 1.5.1 with sass-rails

This is my gem file:

```
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 4.0.2'
gem 'leaflet-rails'

gem 'bourbon'
gem 'neat', '1.5.1'
```

I have

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
@import "grid-settings";
@import "neat/neat";
@import "setting";
```

in my main.scss

and

```
@import "main";
```

in my application.css.scss

If I put neat in application.css.scss I get "Undefined Mixing Error"

I already did bundle install, re-start the serve and clear the cache.

Comment: What is the code around Line 48 of stylesheets/sass/neat/functions/_private.scss?

Comment: This is the code but is not about that file or this line! I more about this !global thing. So I guess is about sass or neat or ruby versions.
<pre> <code>@ function container-shift($shift: $shift) {
  $parent-columns: $grid-columns !global !default;

  @ if length($shift) == 3 {
    $container-columns: nth($shift, 3);
    @ return $container-columns;
  }

  @ else if length($shift) == 2 {
    $container-columns: nth($shift, 2);
    @ return $container-columns;
  }

  @ else {
    @ return $parent-columns;
  }
}</pre> </code>

Comment: Sorry , i don't know how to formatting code in comments...

Comment: Np - fwiw, it's with backticks (`).

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088206/scss-syntax-error-when-compiling

Answer (score 1):

This might help you, seems like this is a known issue: https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/issues/170

Comment: I already saw that issue, thanks. But nothing that can help me to fix my problem. I should have the right versions running. Neat 1.5.1 with sass-rails as they say

Comment: what version of sass are you running (sass -v)?  Also, try "which sass" to make sure it's pointing to the version of sass you think you're using.  maybe it's a path problem? also what version of bourbon are you running?

Comment: sass version: Sass 3.2.19 (Media Mark) which sass: /Users/giorgia_sambrotta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/sass Bourbon: bourbon (3.1.8)

Answer (score 0):

Seems the main problem was the sass/neat folder.
If you're using the gem, you don't have to create one, is just for project without Ruby And Rails.

Is just not very clear in the instruction :)